# ESLint: Using recommended default rules with angularjs applications

Tags: angularjs, eslint

I have recently added ESLint-ing into my angular application and soon realised I needed the [eslint-plugin-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-angular) plugin in order to get my application to be linted correctly.

Prior to this, I was using the extends property in my `.eslintrc` file and setting to `eslint:recommended` to make use of the eslint recommended rule set.

```
{
  "extends": "eslint:recommended"
}
```

I tested this worked by adding a trailing comma to an object definition in my code to make sure I saw an error appear from eslint.

Now, following the guides for the eslint-plugin-angular, I have also installed eslint-config-angular and I see that the quickest way to get started is using the shareable config.

If I use the extends angular config option in place of my current:

```
{
  "extends": "angular"
}
```

I no longer get my error thrown for an unexpected trailing comma.

So, is there a way I can use both angular and `eslint:recommended` in the extends config option?
E.g:

```
{
  "extends": ["angular", "eslint:recommended"]
}
```

(which I know does not work)

If not, does this mean I have to create a rules config object in my `.eslintrc` to mimic the recommended ones from eslint?

```
{
  "extends": "angular",
  "rules" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you using for linting ? (sublime, atom, gulp, the eslint command directly...). I've tested with the eslint command, and `"extends": ["angular", "eslint:recommended"]` should work. 

I did have to install `eslint-plugin-angular` and `eslint-config-angular` globally.

Answer (score 10):

I can't speak to whether or not there was a code change between the time this SO article was entered but I am using `"extends": ["eslint:recommended", "angular"]` in my `.eslintrc` file and it is working fine.  I have it at the same level as the `"env"` property.

My `package.json` file has `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-angular` versions 2.3.0 and 0.5.0, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TypeScript (like Angular2 is) you can use [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint).
There are [eslint rules for tslint](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules) and [tslint-microsoft-contrib](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib) from Microsoft.

Finally, there's a rule set for Angular2: [codelyzer](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer)